# Why ESlint shows Unable to resolve path to module error?

Tags: node.js, eslint

I am running

```
eslint server.js
```

Got error

```
17:24  error    Unable to resolve path to module './routes'  import/no-unresolved

goran@goran-HP-pic-8560p:~/blog_mongo/backend$ pwd
/home/goran/blog_mongo/backend
goran@goran-HP-pic-8560p:~/blog_mongo/backend/routes$ pwd
/home/goran/blog_mongo/backend/routes
```

This is the line

```
const routes = require('./routes');
```

My eslinter.json

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2020": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "airbnb-base"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 12,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
        "indent" : [2, "tab"],
        "no-tabs" : 0
    },
    "settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
          "node": {
            "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Why did I get error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure ESLint by updating the `settings` property of your `.eslintrc.json` file :

```json
"settings": {
  "import/resolver": {
    "node": {
      "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]
    }
  }
}
```